# Load row information from DataTable created with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have the next form.

[image]

This table is created with an AJAX call, here is the code:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlServer + "../webserviceURL", //URL del Web Service
    data: '{"us":"' + sessionStorage.Usuario + '"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    timeout: 600000,
    error: function (xhr) {
        lineas += '<tr><th colspan="8" class="text-center">No se encontraron registros de los cursos.</th></tr>';
        $('#Tabla6').html(lineas);
        bootbox.alert("No se pudo cargar los cursos.");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#Tabla6').dataTable({
            "aaData": JSON.parse(data.d),
            "aoColumns": [{
                "mDataProp": "Id"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "Nombre"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "Contraseña"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "Tipo"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "Correo"
            }, {
                "mData": "",
                "bSortable": false,
                "mRender": function (oObj) {
                    return '<span class="btn btn-success fa fa-edit"></span>';
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Works fine but I want to load the row information when user click the "pencil button" and I dont know exactly how to do this. The only thing I need is load the row information to this method:

```
 $('#Tabla6').on('click', '.glyphicon-edit', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    editarDatosUsu(id);
});
```

editarDatosUsu Method:

```
function editarDatosUsu(id) {
if ($('#U' + id).length) {
    var id = $('#U' + id).attr('data-id');

    $('#IdUs').val(id);
    var rev = $('#U' + id + '-1').html();
    var pass = $('#U' + id + '-2').html();
    var tipo = $('#U' + id + '-3').html();
    var mail = $('#U' + id + '-4').html();

    $('#user').val(rev);
    $('#pass').val(pass);
    $('#tipo').val(tipo);
    $('#mail').val(mail);
}
```

Comment: if u want to read values from table on click of edit u can use $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text(); // 1St td
$(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text();// 2nd td

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```
$("#dashboardTable").on( 'click', '.approveLink', function () {
    var tableRow = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') );
    var row = $(this).parents('tr');
    approveDashboard(tableRow.data().id, row);
```

} );

(where table is the datatable)